# javascript - call exported function from another class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here's the scenario: There is a file called `api.js` which has method `api()` to make api calls. There is another class called `AutoLogout` which has functionality to show autologout modal and logging out user after certain time in case of no activity. These works fine.

`index.js` in `../services`

```
export { default as api } from './api';
// export { api, onResponse } from './api'; tried this as well
export { default as userService } from './userService';
```

`api.js`

```
import userService from './userService';

export function onResponse(response) {
    // returns response to calling function
    return response;
}

async function api(options) {
  const settings = Object.assign(
    {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-correlation-id': Math.random()
          .toString(36)
          .substr(2),
      },
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: options.json != null ? JSON.stringify(options.json) : undefined,
    },
    options,
  );

  const response = await window.fetch(`/api/v0${options.endpoint}`, settings);
  // calling onResponse() to send the response
  onResponse(response);

  if (response.status === 403) return userService.logout();
  if (response.status > 299) throw new Error();
  if (response.status === 204) return true;
  return response.json ? response.json() : false;
}

export default api;
```

Now, in response header I've "x-expires-at" and I want to use it in autologout. So, that if api call is made the user token resets.

`auto-lougout.js`

```
import { userService, api } from '../services';
// import { userService, api, onResponse } from '../services'; tried this as well
export default class AutoLogout {

  constructor() {
    super();
    if (!userService.getUser()) userService.logout();
    // here I am not able to call onResponse() from api.js
    // getting response received from onResponse()
    api.onResponse((resp) => { console.log(resp.headers.get('x-expires-at'))});
  }
}
```

Trying to implement as an example given in this article:

https://zpao.com/posts/calling-an-array-of-functions-in-javascript/

**Here I cannot use `export { api, onResponse };` as `api` is already being used at multiple places in whole project.**

**How do I call `onResponse` function in one js file from another class in another js file ?** **Am I using callback correctly here ? If not, how to use callback correctly in such scenario ?**

Comment: can't you just import your `onResponse` function in your `auto-logout.js` file ?

Comment: @Prasanna tried but didn't work

Comment: did you export your `onResponse` from the api.js  ?

Comment: @Prasanna yes and I am not getting any error.

Comment: please edit you question with what you have done

Comment: @Prasanna updated answer (commented code on top)

Comment: This is not how functions or callbacks work in JavaScript. It's unclear to me what `api.onResponse` should refer to. I think you should be looking into https://nodejs.org/api/events.html .

Comment: Added reference article URL.

Comment: Btw, `AutoLogOut` should not be a `class`. Or if you think you need to instantiate it, at least [you should not do asynchronous stuff in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572).

Answer (score 2):

> Here I cannot use `export { api, onResponse };` as api is already being used at multiple places in whole project.

The correct import/export syntax for your project would be

```
// api.js
export function onResponse() { … }
export default function api() { … }
```

```
// index.js
export { default as userService } from './userService';
export { default as api, onResponse } from './api';
```

```
// elsewhere
import { userService, api, onResponse } from '../services';
// use these three
```

> Am I using callback correctly here?

No, not at all. `onResponse` should not be a function declared in your api.js file, and it should not be exported from there - sparing you all the above hassle.

> If not, how to use callback correctly in such scenario?

Make the callback a *parameter* of the function that uses it:

```
export default async function api(options, onResponse) {
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
  const settings = Object.assign(…);

  const response = await window.fetch(`/api/v0${options.endpoint}`, settings);

  onResponse(response);

  …
}
```

Then at the call of the `api` function, pass your callback as an argument:

```
api(options, resp => {
  console.log(resp.headers.get('x-expires-at'));
});
```